# Multiple BETWEEN and LIMIT operators in SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a result set of two rows.

These two rows are the last rows found between the timespan specified in the BETWEEN operator.

How can I achieve this result?

The code below does not work.

```
SELECT 
DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5
AS october
FROM   solarenergy
WHERE ((DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-01 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-01 23:00:00') LIMIT 1)
   OR ((DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-02 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-02 23:00:00') LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to perform a `UNION` to be able to apply two separate `LIMIT`, as only one can be used per query.  To use individual `LIMIT` clauses, each `UNION` component must be wrapped in `()`

```
(
  SELECT 
  DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5 AS october
  FROM solarenergy
  WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-01 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-01 23:00:00'
  ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
  LIMIT 1
) UNION (
  SELECT 
  DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5 AS october
  FROM solarenergy
  WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-02 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-02 23:00:00'
  ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

If you want to guarantee an order on two rows resulting from the `UNION`, that has to be applied outside the `()` groups at the end

```
(
  SELECT 
  DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5 AS october
  FROM solarenergy
  WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-01 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-01 23:00:00'
  ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
  LIMIT 1
) UNION (
  SELECT 
  DaySum_1+DaySum_2+DaySum_3+DaySum_4+DaySum_5 AS october
  FROM solarenergy
  WHERE DatumUhrzeit BETWEEN '2014-10-02 01:00:00' AND '2014-10-02 23:00:00'
  ORDER BY DatumUhrzeit DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
/* Global ORDER BY after UNION */
ORDER BY october ASC
```